# c# disable specific buttons

Tags: c#, button, foreach, controls

I am working on this project and now realised that I've never really used the "enable"/"disable" functions and now I want to disable specific buttons while others can still run! (want that restart button still works after game has ended)

Can someone help me with this? 
Thanks in advance any answer is appreciated!

```
private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    if (turn)
        b.Text = "X";
    else
        b.Text = "O";

    turn = !turn;
    b.Enabled = false;

    checkForWinner();
}

private void checkForWinner()
{
    bool there_is_a_winner = false;

    if ((A1.Text == A2.Text) && (A2.Text == A3.Text) && (!A1.Enabled))
        there_is_a_winner = true;
    else if ((B1.Text == B2.Text) && (B2.Text == B3.Text) && (!B1.Enabled))
        there_is_a_winner = true;
    else if ((C1.Text == C2.Text) && (C2.Text == C3.Text) && (!C1.Enabled))
        there_is_a_winner = true;

    if (there_is_a_winner)
    {
        disableButtons();

        String winner = "";
        if (turn)
            winner = "O";
        else
            winner = "X";

        MessageBox.Show(winner + "Wins!", "Yay!");

    }//end if
}// End Check For Winner

private void disableButtons()
{
    foreach (Control c in Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
        {
            Button b = (Button)c;
            b.Enabled = false;
        }//end foreach
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your layout ...but if all of the buttons u want to disable are related then put them in one panel ...and with one line

```
panel1.Enabled = false;
```

All of the buttons will be disabled

if they aren't related Maybe You Can Create a `List<Button>` and Loop trough them with a foreach like this

```
foreach(Button B In MyListOfButtons)
{
    B.Enabled=false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer                                                                                 It is a tic tac toe kinda game with 1 panel including 9 buttons A1 - A3 B1 - B3 and C1 - C3      and the restart and exit button. So it disables all buttons when the game ends

Comment: Then U Could Disable The Panel Containing The Button ...and This Will Disable The All Buttons In It

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 private void disableButtons()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < Controls.GetLength(); x++)
            if (Controls[x] is Button)
                Controls[x].Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer!                                                                                         But unfortunately it didn't worked ..

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through all buttons Recursively and then disable them.

```
public static void disableButtons(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
            c.Enabled = false;
        else
            disableButtons(c);
}
```

Then in your code you should pass the panel (or form) contatinig your target Buttons. for example if your buttons are in panel1 then you should use `disableButtons(panel1);`